# Define typescript interface for generalized json

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

I have below json, where carModels contains below format. How to define the Interface ?

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "version": 1.0,
    "cars": [{
        "id": 1,
        "carModelID": "1"
    }],
    "carModels": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tesla"
        },
"2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Benz"
        }
    }
}
```

I used online generator to get the below interface. How to generalize below interface so that, CarModel interface can take any value as key ?

```
export interface Root {
  name: string
  version: number
  cars: Car[]
  carModels: CarModels
}

export interface Car {
  id: number
  carModelID: string
}

export interface CarModels {
  "1": N1
  "2": N2
}

export interface N1 {
  id: number
  name: string
}

export interface N2 {
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

#### Problem

Above interaface for `CarModels` defines `N1` and `N2`....How do generalize the CarModels interface to any type ?

Comment: Use an index signature, and depending on the keys you want, use the types `string` for any key; `number` for numbers as keys (arrays should be used then instead), or \`${number}\` if you want numerical strings as keys (even \`${bigint}\` for only integer strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd write an interface for the `CarModel` then use an index type for the containing structure:

```
interface CarModel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface CarModels {
  [key: string]: CarModel;
}
```